# Understanding associations in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to understand how to use the associations(so that my linq statements are more readable)

I have a table logs, which has many mapping IDs. I have a table with a primary key mapping ID which has permutations of countryID, categoryID, and categoryTypeID. Each of those has that column as a primary key on each of there tables. My understanding is that if i set up my context right i could do something like

```
(from l in datacontext.logs
where l.mappings.category.barId== myNumber
select l)
```

But I cant seem to figure out how to make that happen. Is it possible, and how could i go about setting up my project to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use

```
(from l in datacontext.logs
join m in datacontext.mappings on l.mappingId equals l.mappingid
join c in datacontext.category on m.categoryid equals c.categoryid
where c.barId == myNumber
select l).ToList();
```

I am making assumptions on your table structure based on your question.

Comment: I could (and currently do), but I just find the readability of what im looking for really nice.

Comment: Hmmmm....I find joining the tables more readable - at least from an understandability perspective :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, my associations were backwards. logs is not the parent of mapings, rather mapings is the parent of logs.